# (PHP) Oauth2.0 - Error 401 Google Contacts API

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-php-client

i trying the Google API for contacts but when i want retreive all contacts , i have a error 401 ('Invalid Credenticials')... i don't understand because the token is generated but i can't retreive the contacts.

```html
<p style="background-color:red;">
<a href="destroy.php">se deconnecter</a>
<p>
<?php
 session_start();

  require 'lib/google-api-client/Google/autoload.php';
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('Application de test');
  $client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
  $client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/Gmail/index.php');
  //Acces aux données seulement quand l'user est en ligne
  $client->setAccessType('online');
  //configuration des données auxquels on veut avoir accés
  $client -> setScopes('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds');

  if(isset($_GET['code'])){
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location:http://localhost/Gmail/index.php');
  }

  if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    //Generation du lien pour s'authentifier via l'api Google
    $url =  $client->createAuthUrl();
 ?>

 <a href="<?= $url ?>">Importer Google contacts</a>
<?php
  }else{
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    $token = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
    var_dump($token->access_token);
    var_dump($client->getAccessToken());
    $curl = curl_init('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=50&token='.$token->access_token);
    curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
    curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);
    curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 10);
    $contact_json = curl_exec($curl);
    var_dump($contact_json);
    curl_close($curl) ;
    $contacts = json_decode($contact_json);
    var_dump($contacts);
  }
 ?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q2zW.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: change &token= to &access_token=

Comment: Thanks , it's work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get data back you need to be authenticated as you appear to know.   However you are tagging on the access token using `&token=`

the correct way to do it is `&access_token=`

Example:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=50&access_token='.$token->access_token);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to correct your CURL url use access_token instead of token in url.

```
$curl = curl_init('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=50&access_token ='.$token->access_token);
```